# PHPUnit - Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to test a procedural PHP file that begins with the if statement:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

then proceeds to use the superglobal `$_POST` to get the variable which is then used in an SQL query.

Below is my PHPUnit code that I am trying to use to test the procedural file above:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require '../public_html/PHP/dbconfig.php';
//require '../public_html/PHP/getters/getBranchHeaderPhoto';

class getBranchHeaderPhotoTest extends TestCase {

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $_POST = array();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function checkThatGetBranchHeaderPhotoReturnsTheDirectoryAndImage() {
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST";
        $_POST = array("all");
        ob_start();
        include('../public_html/PHP/getters/getBranchHeaderPhoto.php');
        $contents = ob_get_contents();

        $this->assertNotNull($contents);
    }
}

?>
```

However, when I try and run the test in the command line, running the following cmd `phpunit getBranchHeaderPhotoTest.php`, the following error occurs;

```
There was 1 error:

1) getBranchHeaderPhotoTest::checkThatGetBranchHeaderPhotoReturnsTheDirectoryAndImage
Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

C:\Users\User\Documents\project\project\test\getBranchHeaderPhotoTest.php:21

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I have tried following previous SO answers on this topic but can not pass a request method into the procedural file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `==` (comparison) when you want `=` (assignment). Change:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST";
```

to:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST";
```

If possible, fix the offending code to check the key exists, like with:

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] ?? 'GET') == 'POST')
```

Comment: Correct, mistake on my part. Have changed that to '=' rather than double '='. Consequently, the test outputs another error in that it cannot find the required file in the file I am testing, but it has certainly solved the Undefined Index error, so thank you.